# function call its having side effects on a global variable

Tags: python

I'm working on the knapsack problem from the course: https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:MITx+6.00.2x+3T2019/course/

which has the following input:

```
cows = {"Jesse": 6, "Maybel": 3, "Callie": 2, "Maggie": 5}
```

and I have to return as output a list of lists like:

```
[['Jesse', 'Maybel'], ['Callie', 'Maggie']]
```

The function I have coded up seems to be working fine since it returns the right result:

```
def greedy_cow_transport(cows,capacity):
    ocupied = 0
    current_trip = []
    all_trips = []


    while(True):
        for cow in cows:
            if ocupied+cow[1] < capacity:
                current_trip.append((cow[0])) 
                ocupied += cow[1]
                cows.remove(cow)
            else:

                all_trips.append(current_trip)
                ocupied = 0
                current_trip = []
        if len(cows)==0:
            all_trips.append(current_trip)
            break
    return all_trips
```

The issue is that after calling it once:

```
order = copy.copy(sorted(cows.items(), key=lambda x: x[1],reverse= True ))

greedy_cow_transport(order,capacity)
```

The variable order is an empty list. 
I don't see why this is happening since I'm using the .remove method only inside the scope of the function. Why those this affect my main variable?

Comment: You have two variables that reference the same list, not two lists.

Comment: Scope is irrelevant here. Scope merely defines what names resolve to what objects, they don't restrict where mutator methods can affect objects. For example, you can have a name in a local scope referring to an object which also has a reference in the global scope. Basically, you needed a deepcopy

Comment: Instead take a copy of `cows` in your function, call it something like `remainingcows`. Also you are iterating over a container you are removing from, which often doesn't end well.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```
def modify(arr):
    arr.remove(4)

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 7, 3, 4]
modify(numbers)
print(numbers) # prints [1, 2, 3, 7, 3] (modified)
```

You may expect the passing of arguments to functions to act similar to integers:

```
def modify(i):
    i = 6

j = 7
modify(j)
print(j) # prints 7 (not modified)
```

You might think that Python always makes a copy of the argument to use within the function, but that is not the case. When you do `i = 6`, you are setting the variable name of `i` to reference a **new** object of an integer of value `6`. Therefore, the global `i` isn't modified.

However, when you use `list.remove(x)`, you are modifying the actual object passed as an argument. The variable of name `list` still refers to the original object.

Granted, this explanation may be quite confusing. Adding some `id()` will help clarify things.

```
def modify(arr):
    print(id(arr))
    arr.remove(4)
    print(id(arr)) # they print the same thing

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 7, 3, 4]
modify(numbers)
print(numbers) # prints [1, 2, 3, 7, 3] (modified)
```

Now with the integer:

```
def modify(i):
    print(id(i))
    i = 6
    print(id(i)) # nope, different ids!

j = 7
modify(j)
print(j) # prints 7 (not modified)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've attempted to use `copy.copy`, I assume you understand that python passes references to objects by value for arguments. You just need to keep a reference to the sorted order.

Script

```
$ cat cows.py 
...

order = sorted(cows.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse= True)
order_copy = copy.copy(order)
print(order)
print(greedy_cow_transport(order_copy,capacity))
print(order)
```

Output

```
$ python3 cows.py 
[('Jesse', 6), ('Maggie', 5), ('Maybel', 3), ('Callie', 2)]
[['Jesse'], ['Callie', 'Maggie'], ['Maybel']]
[('Jesse', 6), ('Maggie', 5), ('Maybel', 3), ('Callie', 2)]
```

Note that if you had nested lists, you would need to `deepcopy`.